# Using scanner.js npm package

Tags: javascript, scanning

What are the limitations with evaluation version of scanner.js from Asprise. Is it constrained in features compared to the licensed version or is it that it can be used for evaluation purpose for a smaller duration of time? Evaluation version of scanner.js is available over [here](https://asprise.com/document-scan-upload-image-browser/html-web-scanner-download.html)

Comment: Have you tried reading the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scanner-js)? I don't see any reference to an 'evaluation' version

Comment: I believe the evaluation version is what is distributed as open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [license agreement](https://asprise.com/document-scan-upload-image-browser/html-web-scanner-download.html) says:

> ### IV. EVALUATION PERIOD AND TERMINATION
>
> This License Agreement will commence upon Licensee's first installation of the SOFTWARE and will expire and terminate thirty (30) days thereafter ("EVALUATION PERIOD"). LAB ASPRISE! may terminate this License Agreement if Licensee fails to comply with the terms and conditions of this License Agreement. In such event, Licensee must destroy all copies of the SOFTWARE and all of its component parts. All provisions relating the ownership, disclaimer of warranties, limitation of liability and the general provisions shall survive the termination of this License Agreement.

So it looks like the evaluation has all the features but you are supposed to stop using it after 30 days.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. License terms are pretty clear but I am confused as to the open source version. Since that is distributed under MIT license so I guess 30 days does not apply to that.